# All pairs in an ES6 Map

Tags: javascript, ecmascript-6

In ES6, given a Map, how would one visit pairs of values, where order is unimportant?

If this were arrays, I would do as follows:

```
let arr = ["a", "b", "c", "d"];

for (let i=0; i < arr.length; i++)
  for (let j=i+1; j<arr.length; j++)
    console.log(`${arr[i]},${arr[j]}`);
```

With Maps, I'm struggling to find a way to do something similar in an efficient and elegant manner. Iterators looked like they would do the trick, but I was assuming they would behave like C++ Standard Library iterators, where an iterator can be cloned into independent iterators.

The best I've come up with is:

```
var map = new Map([[0, "a"],[1, "b"],[2, "c"],[3, "d"]]);

for (let key of map.keys()) {
  let log_away = false;

  for (let other_key of map.keys()) {
    if (log_away)
        console.log(`${map.get(key)},${map.get(other_key)}`);
    else
        log_away = (key === other_key);
}
```

This is reasonably succinct, but having to visit all pairs, whether they will be used or not, is hardly efficient. Worse, if one were to try to adapt this to a Set containing large objects, the comparison of keys at the end would have to be a comparison of values, which could be prohibitively expensive.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You can call the `values()` method and then call `Array.from()` on the result to get an array of all the values. Then you can do it as you do with arrays.

```js
const map = new Map([[0, "a"],[1, "b"],[2, "c"],[3, "d"]])

const values = Array.from(map.values())
for (let i = 0; i < values.length; i++)
  for (let j = i + 1; j < values.length; j++)
    console.log(`${values[i]},${values[j]}`)
```

Comment: Cool. I take it Array.from() contains references to the underlying values, rather than copies, making it a reasonably efficient choice. No?

Comment: @Mark If the values are objects: yes, you get a reference to that object, not a copy. Otherwise (i.e. if the values are primitives) you get a copy of that value, because in JavaScript you can't have a reference to a primitive value.

Comment: My implementation ended up being very close to this. The difference being that I used `map.keys()` rather than values.

Answer (score 2):

To add one more loop option to the mix (not better, just an alternative): using the rest operator to always loop through the remaining entries.

```js
let map = new Map([[0, "a"],[1, "b"],[2, "c"],[3, "d"]]);

let arr = [...map.values()] ,v;
while(arr.length > 1){
  [v,...arr] =arr;  
  arr.forEach(v2 => console.log([v,v2].join(',')));
}
```

or do the same in a recursive function (variable) to get an array of pairs:

```js
let map = new Map([[0, "a"],[1, "b"],[2, "c"],[3, "d"]]);

const fn = ([v,...a]) => v ? [...a.map(v2=>[v,v2].join()),...fn(a)] : [];
console.log(fn(map.values()));
```

Comment: In days gone by, I was a Haskell nerd, so a functional-esque implementation has a special attraction... Never mind the solution's concise implementation. I'll branch my code and give this a try. If it performs anywhere near the for-loop implementation, it may be the way I go.  Thanks for encouraging me to dust off the functional-coding parts of my brain.

Answer (score 1):

You could combine the use of `Array.from`, `map.values()` and `some` to create this ES6 solution:

```js
var map = new Map([[0, "a"],[1, "b"],[2, "c"],[3, "d"]]);

Array.from(map.values()).forEach( ([key1], i, a) =>
    a.some( ([key2], j) => i !== j ? console.log(key2, key1) : true )
);
```

This uses the fact that `console.log` does not return a value, so care has to be taken to reuse this in a more practical application. It might therefore be more useful to gather the pairs in an array, which can then be used for processing later:

NB: Use of the spread operator is of course an alternative for `Array.from`:

```js
var map = new Map([[0, "a"],[1, "b"],[2, "c"],[3, "d"]]);

var pairs = [...map.values()].reduce( (acc, [key1], i, a) =>
    (a.some( ([key2], j) => i === j || !acc.push([key2, key1]) ), acc), []
);
console.log(pairs);
```